# Should I cite a paper when a sentence is not a findings of a research work but mentioned in the paper?

Tags: citations, computer-science

**Problem**

In the methodology section of [this paper](http://pike.psu.edu/publications/ht15.pdf), authors mentioned that

> Compared to other social network sites such  as  Facebook  and 
>   Twitter,  Instagram  has  been  less  studied and understood.

I need to cite a sentence like this. However, this is not a findings of this paper.

**My Question**

Will it be okay, if I cite this sentence?

Comment: It's absolutely OK to cite any sentence from any given paper, at least if you represent the sentence in a correct context (for example, don't say that the cited sentence is a finding). However, that citation might not be the best support for the claim being made. On the other hand, sometimes there simply is no better support available.

Comment: Thanks, this is more insightful comment than the posted the answer. You may post this one as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to cite sources that suggest social network sites such as Facebook and Twitter have been studied more than others such as Instagram. The quote you provide seems supportive, so you can cite it. When citing, be careful to ensure that your claims are supported by the authors' work. E.g., in this instance, favour phrases such as *suggest*, *hint*, *remark*, ... rather than *found*, *show*, *discover*, ...

Comment: Thanks for your very insightful answer. Can you please let me know, what does it mean (in terms of hint / suggest / found....) when we do not include any of the words (suggest/hint/remark/found/show....) and just include the authors sentence (Compared to other social network............)?

Comment: @Md.SabbirAhmed If you quote the authors, then you could write: _X et al. remark that "[c]ompared to other social network sites such as Facebook and Twitter, Instagram has been less studied and understood"~[Y]_. There are many formulations.

Answer (score 1):

If you take others work then you need to cite it. Otherwise it is called plagiarism.

Comment: I do not have any intention to do plagiarism as I do research to work for the people, not to present a good number of publications. My question was "can I cite this sentence as it is not a findings of that paper?"

Comment: All the contents of their paper is their work whether you think it is a finding or not.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: A correct answer to a different question.

Comment: By _not a finding_, I think @Md.SabbirAhmed means the authors suggest/hint/remark rather than formally _find/show/discover_